# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) using unless

Tags: ruby, arguments

I'm using unless to stop execution of a line if you are on a certain page (home page)

my current code looks like the following:

```
on_page(CleanHomePage).products unless on_page.url.include?('home')
```

where CleanHomePage is a PageObject that has a link that i'm calling products.  You do not have to do this step if you are on the home page, so I want to check the url for "home".

I tried the code above but to all my effort i still get `ArgumentError`: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1), which I don't understand because ('home') is the argment to include? and on_page.url.include? is the argment to unless.  Thanks in advance for help

Comment: are you trying to test with `unless` on the `url` part of the condition or on the `on_page` method? Would be good if you post the `on_page` method... At the first use you are giving an argument to the `on_page` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `on_page` method takes 1 argument but you are not giving it any when you call it inside the "unless" condition.

```
on_page(CleanHomePage).products unless on_page(put_something_here).url.include?('home')
```

I know nothing about the on_page method, but the stuff you are doing seems pretty weird.  You can get the URL of the current request in Rails with something like `request.path` or `request.url`.

Comment: Thanks..should have been unless browser.url where browser is a Watir webdriver browser